# scalafix.sbt.ScalafixFailed: TestError

Tags: scala, jenkins, scalafix

I have a unit test written using scalatest and running fine locally.
But on jenkins it fails with no specific error, just this:

```
[error] (scalafixAll) scalafix.sbt.ScalafixFailed: TestError
```

No test method is mentioned in traces, hence no hint about the cause.

How to really find the cause?